# How to compare two binary classification models

Tags: classification

I am training two different binary classification models (LGBM, Catboost) on the same CV splits of a moderately imbalanced dataset.

I would like to compare their performance. Obviously, if we are to compare them globally we can compare their corresponding metrics (e.g. AUC).

However, I am interested to compare their error profile - e.g. do they make the same mistakes?

This is meant to check whether ensembling them is likely to be of benefit or not. Obviously, the best way to check that is to ensemble them and see how the ensemble would perform. But I am still curious in how different their individual predictions are. I wonder what metric would be meaningful?

Maybe rank correlation in the way they rank the samples according to the confidence score of the sample belonging to the minority class?

Answer (score 0):

To assess the ranking of ranking models, it is common to use metrics such as [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). Another very interesting metric is the F1-score, which provides an average (harmonic) between precision and recall.

There are a number of metrics to measure ranking that allow you to compare 2 models like the ones you are using. There is no single metric. Generally, the problem you are working on will require either high accuracy (low errors, eg plant species classification) or high recall (low false positives, eg disease diagnosis). As there is a trade-off between these two metrics, what they usually do is evaluate the scenario, seeking greater accuracy or recall. The same goes for other metrics.

On this site there is a list of metrics, many quite common, others more specific that they evaluate considering global and local aspects, data with the presence of outliers, etc:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Additionally, to measure dissimilarity between classes, you can use some dissimilarity metric like [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

---

One way of applying precision/recall/f1 to analyze each of the **classes** would be to analyze its support (number of occurrences of each classes in the set of predictions made).

For example, with [sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support):
If the metric is (here best value is 1 and worst is 0)
`precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='micro') = (0.3., 0.3, 0.5).` 
we could say that there were similar mistakes for samples `i=0, 1` (both given 0.3) but not for the `i=2`.

For **individual samples**, you can apply the Jacard index. For example,
`jaccard_score(y_true[k], y_pred[k]) = 0.6`
will be better than the prediction that has `jaccard_score(y_true[j], y_pred[j]) = 0.3.`

If `jaccard_score(y_true[q], y_pred[q]) = jaccard_score(y_true[p], y_pred[p]), then samples corresponding to index` p`and`q` had similar mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It is not clear how this answers the question about how to compare the particular predictions made instead of overall performance in terms of, say, precision or recall. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Student I really hope you don't consider this discouraging but this post almost reads like it is generated by AI.

Comment: @Nick, that's not a problem, the AI has been quite efficient in many tasks. However, I confess that I spent more than 1 hour typing and exploring the question until I got to a reasonable level that maybe can contribute. Many questions with an "open formulation" character end up having a more open answer, possible paths. As a philosopher would say, as important as an answer is question formulation. Furthermore today, that AI can help a lot. If the person wants to compare bananas with apples, there is probably a metric that can help them, although some comparisons may not be as usual/meaningful.